# path css issue to fetch fonts

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts

I had some issue with `font-awesome-rails` gem, so I decided to download `font-awesome` fonts, put it in a `fonts` folder in my `asset` directory. In my `application.css.scss`, I import `@import "font-awesome";`and in `font-awesome.css.scss.erb`, I put

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot')%>');
    src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix')%>') format('eot'), url('<%=    asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.woff')%>') format('woff'), url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.ttf')%>') format('truetype'), url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome')%>') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

after having set `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")`. But I still can't get any font. Someone can hep ?

Answer (score 0):

I make a fonts folder inside the stylesheets one and use **url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot')** to access to it.

I don't know if is the best practice but works for me.